# FB api v1.0 new Permissions

Tags: facebook

I have a app with some permissions that only exist on API V1.0 (I'm working on migrating them to V2.2),

but in the meantime I need a new permission "publish_actions". If I send a review to Facebook I can still use the API V1.0 permissions or I can't? how can keep my permissions "read_stream" of API V1.0 and add a new one?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send in specific permissions, so you can just send in `publish_actions` without `read_stream` and it should be no problem. Just keep in mind that you will lose access to `read_stream` completely after April 2015. I assume you know that it will only get approved for platforms without a Facebook client.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! and yes I know, I will change from read_stream to only read stream of the actual user. But I want to keep that permission until Apr 2015